# Retrieving file from source control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Hi guys when I open my solution from source control(TFS 2013) in the morning some folders in a class library project does not load but they are in the windows explorer so I had to "Include in project" the folder after showing  all files in the solution explorer but there are no contents even though i "Get Lastest(Recursive)" but I checked the web(Tfs) in the code -> explorer there are files shown in the tree view. Is there a problem with tfs? or visual studio? or both? what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have files checked-in TFS but your project file in TFS doesn't have those files included. Also, when you get latest from TFS looks like you override the local changes.

Comment: Get latest from source control explorer and it should download the files and then add those files to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have three(ish) suggestions:

1. You have the directory with the included files mapped to a different place on your local drive.  You can check this my looking at your workspace mappings (File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces).  If you have more than one workspace then make sure you're using the right one.
2. You can force TFS to download files that it believes it has already downloaded.  Instead of GetLatest, choose Get Specific version (this may be on the same menu or under Advanced - can't remember for 2010).  Check Overwright writeable and all files and select Get.
3. Install TFS Power tools and try adding the files that way (i.e. through windows explorer)
4. This isn't really a suggestion, as I don't believe it will work, but if the above don't, try it.  As above, select get Specific version, but instead of Latest version, select Changeset and choose changeset 1.  THIS WILL DELETE ALL FILES IN YOUR WORKSPACE.  The do a get latest as normal.

HTH